# Date fields randomly not updating in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am using Rails 4.0.2 and Ruby 2.0.0. I have two date fields (performance_start and performance_end). When i enter values into these fields, they get submitted with the other parameters but the update query randomly excludes those fields or includes them in the update query.

Any idea why this is happening? I can't seem to figure out why it does this. Any help would be appreciated.

This is an example of the output i see in the command prompt when i submit this form (note only one date is being updated in this example even though both are passed in):

```
Processing by LapsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ol2312IJT3om5ihpIWeLfGziLMlgbDU5bRllMTi76KM=", "lap"=>{"staff_id"=>"1", "activity_id"=>"1", "person_id"=>"1", "job_title"=>"Software Developer", "performance_start"=>"12/01/2013", "performance_end"=>"12/31/2013", "other_billing_code"=>"", "project_labor_code"=>"", "paid_from_field"=>"0", "will_any_of_this_work_occur_in_us"=>"0", "billing_rate_currency"=>"", "billing_rate"=>"", "billing_rate_frequency"=>"Male", "billable_days"=>"", "notes"=>"testing", "aou_number"=>"", "aou_identity_black"=>"0", "aou_identity_native"=>"0", "aou_identity_south_asian"=>"0", "aou_identity_hispanic"=>"0", "aou_identity_asian_pacific"=>"0", "aou_is_veteran"=>"0", "aou_veteran_status_selection"=>"0", "aou_is_service_disabled"=>"0", "aou_emergency_contact_name"=>"", "aou_emergency_contact_address_line1"=>"", "aou_emergency_contact_phone"=>"", "aou_home_contact_name"=>"", "aou_home_address"=>"", "aou_home_phone"=>""}, "id"=>"5"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Person Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "people"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Lap Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "laps".* FROM "laps" WHERE "laps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "laps" SET "notes" = $1, "performance_start" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "laps"."id" = 5  [["notes", "testing"], ["performance_start", Sat, 12 Jan 2013], ["updated_at", Mon, 23 Dec 2013 14:27:54 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
```

Below are the two form fields in my form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@lap, :html => { role: "form"}) do |f| %>

<%= f.input :performance_start, :label => false, :wrapper => :append, :class => "form-group" do %>
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-right"> Performance Start </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <%= f.input_field :performance_start, as: :string, :required => true, :class => "col-xs-7 col-sm-5 datepicker" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <span class="help-button" data-rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="mm/dd/yyyy" title="Date Format">?</span>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= f.input :performance_end, :label => false, :wrapper => :append, :class => "form-group" do %>
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-right"> Performance End </label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <%= f.input_field :performance_end, as: :string, :required => true, :class => "col-xs-7 col-sm-5 datepicker" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <span class="help-button" data-rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="mm/dd/yyyy" title="Date Format">?</span>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the update method in the scaffolded controller:

```
def update
  @lap = Lap.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @lap.update(lap_params)
      if @lap.status.blank?
        @lap.status = "Draft"
      end
      format.html { redirect_to @lap, notice: 'Lap was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @lap.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The schema for the table is below:

```
create_table "laps", force: true do |t|
  ...
  t.date     "performance_start"
  t.date     "performance_end"
  ...
end
```

the lap_params method is a private method in my controller and is as follows (ommitting unrelated fields):

```
def lap_params
  params.require(:lap).permit(..., :performance_start, :performance_end, ...)
end
```

Comment: Please show us your form(s) and the appropriate controller methods.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.0.2 with Ruby 2.0.0

Comment: Do you use `strong_parameters`? What are your `permit` and `require`?

Comment: Added that into the question. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've actually entered data in the form for both `performance_start` and `performance_end`, I would guess that one (or both) parameters haven't been modified from the original record, so there's no reason for rails to update it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm definitely entering a different value than what was in those fields previously so it should trigger an update but isn't for some reason

Comment: Hmm... is there anything else in the logs during the update?  Also, if you're using `strong_parameters`, how are you generating the list in your controller?

Comment: What i pasted was the full output of the console. Is there any other logs that i should be checking? The lap_params variable is a private method with all the fields that can be updated listed in it (ommitting unrelated variables from this): `def lap_params
      params.require(:lap).permit(..., :performance_start, :performance_end, ...)
    end`

Comment: Yes, check `log/development.log`

Comment: Thanks. Checked that and it has the same output as the command prompt had

Comment: and there's _nothing_ else in the log around the same time as the update, even if it seems unrelated?

Comment: Nothing else unfortunately. Do you think this could be a date formatting issue? I am passing it in the format mm/dd/yyyy but it's actually storing it in the format yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Yes, I think it's something along those lines, which is why I was asking if there was anything else in the logs, it seems it's being rejected (either due to missing parameter, or doesn't match validation)

Comment: Okay makes sense. I'll try to format it the way rails is saving it and see if that does the trick. thanks again for your help with this.